# biblatex: Mixing biblatex-dw styles with other styles

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, biblatex-dw

I use `biblatex` with `style=footnote-dw` for my citations displayed with `\cite{key}`. But now I want to use `\printbibliography` as if I have used `style=numeric` in the optional parameter of the `biblatex` package.

Comment: Do you mean simply `\usepackage[citestyle=footnote-dw,bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}`?

Comment: @JosephWright I already tested this out because I read this in the manuals, but this line of code produces some errors:

    `! Package etoolbox Error: Boolean '\ifbbx:annotation' undefined.

    See the etoolbox package documentation for explanation.
    Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
     ...                                              
                                                  
    l.5     citation here\cite{key}`

Comment: I don't think you can mix the `numeric` bibstyle with a non-numeric bibliography style.  What do you want the final output of the bibliography to look like? Should it be alphabetical but with each item numbered, or do you want the references in citation order?

Comment: @AlanMunn, an alphabetical order would be the best, but it does not matter if this isn't possible. I need the citations in footnotes (as `style=footnote-dw` successfully does) but I need a change in the output of the `\printbibliography`. The "footnote style" does not have much margin/padding in the list of literature and I miss the title emphasized or the ISBN.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting section 1.2 of the `biblatex-dw` manual:

> The styles are built in a very entangled way which means that the
>   combination of a biblatex-dw style with another style is not possible
>   without fail.

If you really need to have numeric labels in the bibliography -- which are superfluous for a verbose style like `footnote-dw` --, try

```
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose-inote,bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Just recognized that the numeric labels are unneccessary with `footnote-dw`, thanks lockstep. I just want to have the title emphasized and the ISBN displayed in the list of literature. Also I need to change the margin of the entries. A empty line between the entries would be very nice since the are currently very close to eachothers.

Comment: @Jan The ISBN should already be displayed. For the spacing between entries, try `\setlength{\bibitemsep}{4.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.0pt}`. And please consider to acccept my answer (and to upvote it as soon as you have enough reputation).

Comment: With `\usepackage[citestyle=verbose-inote,bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}` there are ISBN displayed in the footnotes and the list of literature. How to disable this in the footnotes?

With `\usepackage[style=footnote-dw]{biblatex}` there are no ISBN at all. How to emphasize the title or display the ISBN?

And yes, I will consider it.

Comment: @Jan Try `\usepackage[style=verbose-inote]{biblatex}\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{isbn}}`.